# Show PRIVILEGES in Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions

How can I list the PRIVILEGES for a user in Windows 2003 Server (SP2) ?
I know I can do something like this:
**`C:\ whoami /priv`**

This only lists my current user. I need to specify a user and retrieve a list of privileges.

Comment: Is this a workgroup or a domain? Do you have the other user's password?

Comment: workgroup, local user - do not have the other user's password.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if you have the password information for the other user, you can simply do this:

`runas /user:otherUser cmd.exe`

For example, I just did that for a SQL Server 2008 account on the same computer and I could examine its privileges and etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local user you can use the command

```
net user username
```

If it's on a domain use the command

```
net user username /domain
```

Comment: I don't believe that will show the users privileges on the local machine.

Comment: That won't do what the poster is asking for. Privileges aren't group memberships (which is the only thing even remotely close to what the poster is looking for that the "NET USER" command will return).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a process for that user running, you can open the process properties in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and the security tab will list the privileges in that process token.

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities for you.

The first is kind of ugly, but there is another command called `showpriv.exe` that does the reverse of `whoami /priv` - you give it a privilege name and it shows what users/groups have that privilege. You could script it to loop through all the privileges and show users/groups with that privilege - and further script it to list the users in groups instead of groups.

The second is based on Powershell - get the [Powershell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) and use the `Get-Privilege` cmdlet. You get your own privileges by running:

```
Get-Privilege
```

You can get it for another user by running:

```
$identity = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity("domain\username")
Get-Privilege $identity
```